# Sort elemenets ascending and descending with data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to sort it ascending via below code

```
function getSorted(selector, attrName) {
    return $($(selector).toArray().sort(function(a, b){
        var aVal = parseInt(a.getAttribute(attrName)),
            bVal = parseInt(b.getAttribute(attrName));
        return aVal - bVal;
    }));
}


var sorthtml = getSorted('.instrument', 'data-sortpopular');
$(".vddl-list").html(sorthtml);
```

But unable to sort it descending , I tried something like below

```
sorthtml.toArray().reverse();
$(".vddl-list").html(sorthtml);
```

As asked in comments : below is sample html

```
<div class="vddl-list" data-sortpopular="12">
something
</div>
<div class="vddl-list" data-sortpopular="2">
something
</div>
<div class="vddl-list" data-sortpopular="3">
something
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the html

Comment: Did you try to reverse the subtraction? `aVal - bVal --> bVal - aVal`

Comment: Include the actual input/output and the expected output please.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel and use [tinysort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/)

Comment: @JeremyThille Using `sort()` on an array doesn't feel like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Isn't OP trying to sort HTML elements? Not just an array

Answer (score 2):

Your `getSorted` function is broken, here is a fix, then it will work well!

If you want the ascending order, just comment the last two lines, else, you'll get the reversed version (descending order) ;)

Hope this helps!

```js
function getSorted(selector, attrName) {
    return $(selector).toArray().sort(function(a, b){
        var aVal = parseInt(a.getAttribute(attrName)),
            bVal = parseInt(b.getAttribute(attrName));
        return aVal - bVal;
    });
}


var sorthtml = getSorted('.instrument', 'data-sortpopular');
$(".vddl-list").html(sorthtml);
sorthtml.reverse();
$(".vddl-list").html(sorthtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="instrument" data-sortpopular="12">
something 12
</div>
<div class="instrument" data-sortpopular="2">
something 2
</div>
<div class="instrument" data-sortpopular="3">
something 3
</div>

<div class="vddl-list"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: you can create function for reverse like below where just reverse the order of substraction

```
sorthtml = sorthtml.toArray().reverse(function(a, b){
        var aVal = parseInt(a.getAttribute('data-sortpopular')),
            bVal = parseInt(b.getAttribute('data-sortpopular'));
        return bVal - aVal;
});
$(".vddl-list").html(sorthtml);
```